# Unable to open firefox in new tab using protractor

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, protractor

I'm using protractor to run my E2E cases in chrome,firefox and IE.

Below code works fine in chrome - opens new tab and hits google.com

```
let url = "https://google.com";
return browser.executeScript("return window.open(arguments[0], '_blank')", url);
```

For firefox, new tab is gettng opened but google.com is not hit and tab closes immediately with error - " AssertionError: WebDriverError: InternalError: too much recursion"

I also tried below code as well.it works fine in chrome but not in firefox.

```
function openNewTab(linkname) {
return browser.driver.executeScript(function (arguments) {
    var linkname = arguments;
    (function (link) {
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.setAttribute('href', linkname);
        link.dispatchEvent((function (e) {
            e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
            return e;
        }(document.createEvent('MouseEvents'))))
    }(document.createElement('a')));
}, linkname);
}
```

is there any other alt for opening new tab in firefox using protractor?

I tried as below answer by yong but it throws then. is not defined error.

```
   function openNewTab(linkname) {
   browser.driver.executeScript(function(arguments) {
        var linkname = arguments;
    var d = document,
        a = d.createElement('a');
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.href = linkname;
    a.innerHTML = '.';
    d.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
}, linkname)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For your sencond way, I think the cause fail on firefox is firefox not support dispatchEvent() or initMouseEvent() or createEvent().

You can try below code:

```
browser.driver.executeScript(function (url) {
        var d = document,
            a = d.createElement('a');
        a.target = '_blank';
        a.href = url;
        a.innerHTML = '.';
        d.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    }, "https://google.com");
```

Comment: Hi I have tried ur code,but im missing some parameter.I have edited my actual code, Can u please modify as per my question? and what is <url open on new tab> here?param? or comments?